# How to align text in middle of div with multi resolution font size

Tags: jquery, html, css

I made a block it contain two different types of text one represent the sign which has to come on the top right side of the block while the other span text is number which has to be displayed in the middle of the div.

The problem is whatever i do i cant able to make my text number position in the middle of that div. Secondly the same text if i use on different resolution than my box works fine and it automatically re-size and adjusted its width and height through my JS code but the font always remain as same size. I have used percentage in font size in thought it will increase the size on larger resolution but it didnt work. I have to use this html in mobile phones and each mobile phone has different resolution where this block has to be shirnk or get large based on the resolution size but Font is not getting adjust at all. i am kind of a new person in css and html5 kindly help me to achieve this goal.

here is the fiddle preview of my code
http://jsfiddle.net/E2vbe/

here is my code

```
$(function() {
    var pilewidth2 = $('#A').width();
    $('#A').height(pilewidth2);
    $('#B').height(pilewidth2);
}); //this make my div with same height and width on any resolution

<div id="A" style="vertical-align:middle;" class="cardPile2">
    <span class="TileScore">$</span>
    <span class="TileCharacter">44</span>
</div>
<div id="B" class="cardPile2">
    <span class="TileScore">%</span>
    <span class="TileCharacter">33</span>
</div>
```

my css

```
.cardPile2 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #ffd;
    float: left;
    width: 9%;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    background: #666;
    color: #fff;
    opacity:0.9;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.TileScore
{
    float:right;font-size:small;padding-right:10px;
}

.TileCharacter
{
    color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: Can you attach any screen shot how do want to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a function to perform what you're looking for (I think). I believe it will work for you in most if not all circumstances... multiple lines, etc...

I also had to update a few of your styles to get it done but here is a [WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/E2vbe/25/).

Here is the function:

```
function positionText() {
    $('.cardPile2').each(function (i, ele) {
        var width = $(this).outerWidth();
        $(this).css({height: width + 'px'});

        // scale font sizes
        var charFontScale = 16/86;
        var scrFontScale = 13/86;
        var charFontSize = Math.round(width * charFontScale);
        var scrFontSize = Math.round(width * scrFontScale);

        // top right align the characters
        var chr = $(this).find('.TileCharacter').css({'font-size': charFontSize + 'px'});
        var chrWidth = $(chr).outerWidth();
        var chrHeight = $(chr).outerHeight();
        $(chr).css({top: Math.floor(width/2 - chrHeight/2) + 'px', left: Math.floor(width/2 - chrWidth/2) + 'px'});

        // center the scores
        var score = $(this).find('.TileScore').css({'font-size': scrFontSize + 'px'});
        var scrWidth = $(score).outerWidth();
        $(score).css({left: (width - scrWidth) + 'px'});
    });
}
```

Let me know if that gets the job done for you.

**EDIT**

I've updated the fiddle to scale the fonts proportionally as well. Edited function is above.

Comment: I think you reversed the place of the letter & the score. also: the problem can be solved without any script. pure CSS solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure in the OP he says that the number goes in the center of the box... "the other span text is number which has to be displayed in the middle of the div"

Comment: Did you never see a scrable game before? your reversing the displays.. believe me.

Comment: Original poster never mentioned scrabble although we could infer that was his intent. I was just going on what I read in his post.

Comment: yes i didnt mentioned scrabble but the placement i think should be like scrabble thanks avrahamcool for explaining this. Though i am not making scrabble block but the block should have one character on top-left smaller and other in the middle of div.

Comment: the new fiddle is not working on FF (I didn't try other browser) when I'm resizing the page.

Comment: Yeah, I never programmed it to change with a change in window size. My bad. I didn't anticipate the user re-sizing the browser... anyway it was an easy fix... fiddle link in answer has been updated to work as you expected now.

Comment: Thanks ryan it works though avrahamcool solution is also good but you made text size fix as along resolution and settings so i go with your answer. One point to avrahamcool for his help as well...Thanks guys you both are best.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/E2vbe/8/)

my solution works without fixing the line-height (its better not to fix it, in case of multiple lines, or different font sizes)

*Tested on*: IE10, IE9, FF, Chrome

without changing the markup: add this to your **CSS**

```
.TileCharacter
{
    color:yellow; /*From your CSS*/
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
}
.TileCharacter:before
{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

also you can remove the `text-align:center;` & `vertical-align:middle;` from `.cardPile2` rule.

Comment: the character in middle now adjusted but the font size of text is not adjusting and getting out of the box rather than getting shrink. i have use mobile resolution like 320X480 and test your code. To demonstrate this problem I have change the .cardPile2 width to 3% please check http://jsfiddle.net/E2vbe/24/  . I am trying to make a solution flexible for anykind of resolution in mobile phones. Kindly suggest me what is best way for it?

Comment: I just solved your centering problem. to change the font-size based on the size of the view-port you will have to use [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

Comment: but those 2 questions are not related. so you can use my solution and add the font-size handling. all of this without script. [as should be done]

Comment: but if i need to use media queries then i have to do find all kinds of resolution of mobiles and hardcode their width and height. I think JS here is required to target all kinds of mobile phones

Answer (score 0):

Apply line-height css property to spans like this

```
.TileScore
{
    float:right;font-size:small;padding-right:10px;
    line-height:4;
}

.TileCharacter
{
    line-height:4;
    color:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make make it responsive, I have given the `padding` in % . This might be what you want.
http://jsfiddle.net/E2vbe/15/  And the `font-size` can be changed using media queries instead of JS for different screen resolutions.

Comment: what happend to the tiles height?

Comment: You mean height has changed ?

Comment: You can set whatever height you want and adjust the values accordingly (top).

Comment: OK, so you need to specify the top.. you should mention that in your answer.. becuase its a big downsize.

Comment: Can you explain please, how its a downside ?

Comment: because if he wants to change the height, he have to alter 2 CSS rules, and calculate the exact amount of space he have to use. its calling for mistakes. *a fluid layout should be really **fluid***.